# Drawing shapes with transparent colors much slower than opaque colors in Java

Tags: java, performance, transparency

I am currently working on making a Java videogame with a few friends. It is a top-down RPG that is drawn with tiles of different types. I just added a day/night cycle to the game, and found that using transparent colors to draw to the screen is very slow. I recently learned how to make colors transparent by adding an alpha-value after the RGB values, and it works very well, but as I said, it is slow. I tried switching between transparent colors and opaque colors and discovered that the lag is because of the transparency. Basically, after a tile is drawn, it calls the method for getting the desired transparency factor, makes a new color, and calls g.fillRect() over the tile. This is done for every tile on screen.

I would like to know if there is another way to have a transparent overlay without just drawing the overlay over the whole window, because we want to be able to add light sources that replace the transparency for specific tiles. The tiles are drawn to the screen from a spritesheet. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Consider [jogl](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) or similar.